# Add elements to beginning of jQuery collection

Tags: jquery

I'd like to add some new elements to the beginning of a jQuery collection.

The `add` method doesn't add elements in the order I want. http://jsfiddle.net/F8Z7v/1/

The HTML

```
<p>p</p>
<i>i</i>
<b>b</b>
```

The javascript

```
// will be ordered according to the order they appear on the document
$('i').add('p').add('b');

// new elements will always appear at the end
$('i').add('<u id="u"></u>');
$('<u id="u"></u>').add('i');

// taking control of the ordering using raw arrays
var u = $('<u id="u"></u>').toArray();
u.push($('i')[0])
$(u);
```

The last option works, but it's a bit ugly. Is there a cleaner way to do it?

-- Edit --

My solution based on the comments:

```
// Create the collection you want at the beginning
var newElems = $('<div></div>');

// Push new collection to it
newElems.push.apply(newElems, $('i, b, p'));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you have to rely on the internal ordering of elements in jQuery objects?

Comment: Why so you console,the .add methods?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm merging an existing collection with a collection of new elements so I can insert them on the DOM. It's necessary to merge them because I must make groups of the elements.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan I just copied/pasted from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8Z7v/1/)

Comment: @Eduardo, if I understand your requirements correctly, then you can use plain arrays instead of jQuery objects for that purpose. DOM insertion methods like `after()`, `append()`, etc. can take arrays as arguments (or be applied arrays of arguments). This looks simpler than wrapping the arrays in jQuery objects.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi is right, you should check other methods for adding elements as mentioned in above comment.

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid. It looks dirty, but it's the only solution I came up with. =/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery `.add()` doesn't add elements in that order. it's mentioned in the documentation of it.

> Do not assume that this method appends the elements to the existing
>   collection in the order they are passed to the .add() method. When all
>   elements are members of the same document, the resulting collection
>   from .add() will be sorted in document order; that is, in order of
>   each element's appearance in the document. If the collection consists
>   of elements from different documents or ones not in any document, the
>   sort order is undefined. To create a jQuery object with elements in a
>   well-defined order, use the $(array_of_DOM_elements) signature.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/add/

You will have to do `.push` only, if you want to add at the last of the collection.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem some time ago and resolved it like this:

```
$.fn.addTo = function(array) {
    var newArray = $(this).toArray();
    array.each(function(){
        newArray.push(this);
    });
    return $(newArray);
}

var items = $("i").add("b").add("p");
items = $("<ul></ul>").addTo(items);
```

Also, since i return jQuery object this `addTo()` method can be a part of method chain.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `.prepend()`?

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each
>   element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: I want to insert them on the DOM after ordering. `jQuery.prepend` would work fine if I didn't have to group the collection in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) method to retrieve DOM nodes and pass them in an array to `$()`, e.g:

```
$( $('#a').get().concat($('.b').get()).concat($('c').get()) );
```

or if it's enough to get only the 1st element then here's a simplified version

```
$([ $('#a')[0], $('.b')[0], $('c')[0] ]);
```

but be aware that in this case undefined values are added to array if the selector didn't match